# replace new lines with "" in C#

Tags: c#, xml, replace, newline

I want to convert this:

```
  <translation>
      1 Sənədlər
    </translation>
```

to 
  `<translation>1 Sənədlər</translation>` in XML using C#.

Please help me. Only translation tags.
I tried this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        xdoc.Save("path, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

But it does not remove the new lines between `<translation>` tags.

Comment: PLEASE use the formatting help and the preview to make sure your question looks at least legible BEFORE you post it.

Comment: Try replacing `System.Environment.NewLine` with `""` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new line is determined in the code by "`\n`" and possibly also "`\r`". You can simply remove these:

```
string xmlString = "<translation>\r\n1 Sənədlər\r\n</translation>"; // With the 'new lines'

xmlString = xmlString.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```

This will result in:

```
<translation>
1 Sənədlər
</translation>
```

Becomming:

```
<translation>1 Sənədlər</translation>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This may accidentally work for this specific string but will actually *mangle* data found inside `CDATA` sections. It isn't needed either - XML ignores newlines just like HTML. You have to use the encoded forms (&#xD, &#xA) if you want them to be preserved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos XML doesn't ignore newlines *as part of text content*.  If they were ignored, the question wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

what you have should work. you can validate by dumping the XDocument to a string variable to confirm if the SaveOptions is removing the formatting.

for eg: i tried the below and content does not have any formatting including newlines and whitespaces.

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Team", new XElement("Developer", "Sam")));
        var content = xmlDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out newlines manually in an environment-sensitive way by using

```
var content = xmlString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)
```

Comment: First, an XML document doesn't have an environment. Second, replacing such characters will probably break `CDATA` sections. Third, XML *ignores* newlines anyway. You have to use the encoded forms (eg `&#xD`) if you want to preserve newlines

Answer (score 0):

XML defines two types of whitespace: significant and insignificant:

Insignificant whitespace is the whitespace between elements where text content doesn't occur, whereas significant whitespace is the whitespace within elements that contain text content. You might find the graphic in [this article](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/Whitespace.aspx) useful to show the difference.

What you have in your `translation` element is *significant* whitespace; the element contains text so it is assumed to be part of the element contents.  Without a schema or DTD that says it can be collapsed, no amount of changing the whitespace handling on read or write is going to remove this. These options only relate to the *insignificant* whitespace.

What you can do is apply your own processing: using LINQ to XML, you can trim the whitespace of all elements that contain only text using something like this:

```
var textElements = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(element => element.Nodes().All(node => node is XText));

foreach (var element in textElements)
{
    element.Value = element.Value.Trim();
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LPiMGs) for a demo.