# Pretty-print XML files without text content

Tags: c#, xml, pretty-print

I know that pretty print questions have been asked countless times, but i haven't found any information to solve my problem.

I am writing a tool to strip xml files of their contents and later insert new content to the skeleton that was left.

Basically the xml looks like this beforehand:

```
<file>
    Some text which is not in a tag (not my decision)
    <index>Index 1</index>
    <entry att1='val1' att2='val2'>
        <text>some text</text>
        <relations>some information</relations>
    </entry>
</file>
```

additional to the text and relations subelements there are other subelements.
What i do is to delete all sub elements of all entry elements beside the relations element.
Afterwards the file gets saved and this is where the fun starts.

I use the `XmlDocument` class , set the `PreserveWhitespace` Property to true to have all the texts keep their whitespaces and linebreaks. I save the file by using a `XmlWriter` created with `XmlWriterSettings` set to intend and to replace all linebreaks with the `Environment.NewLine.

The file ends up having all kind of entry elements in one line until a new index element starts, which has some text in it. Which is really strange, since there is text in the relations elements as well.

Using the `XDoc` class to try to pretty-print the output didn't work as well. I just want all elements on a new line each.

Comment: The answer I gave in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38659851/1320845) might give you some insight as to why this is happening. No easy solutions come to mind, unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format XML String to Print Friendly XML String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string)